# Where to put this code so it displays in all comments

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, comments

I downloaded the "like/dislike counter" plugin on wordpress and wish to include a like/dislike button in all comments.

The code for the like and dislike button is:

```
<?php if(function_exists('like_counter_c')) { like_counter_c("Like"); } ?>
<?php if(function_exists('dislike_counter_c')) {dislike_counter_c("Dislike"); } ?>
```

I have tried placing it in different parts of comments.php but it either puts it above or below the comments and NOT on all of them as desired.

Does anyone have any idea where I should put it?

Below is the code from my comments.php :

```
<?php
// Do not delete these lines
    if (!empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) && 'comments.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
        die ('Please do not load this page directly. Thanks!');

    if ( post_password_required() ) { ?>
        <p class="nocomments">This post is password protected. Enter the password to view comments.</p>
    <?php
        return;
    }
?>

<!-- You can start editing here. -->

<?php if (have_comments()) { ?>
  <div id="commentspost"><a name="commentspost"></a>
    <h2 class="title"><?php comment_type_count();?> <?php _e('Comments', 'wpzoom'); ?></h2>
    <ol class="normalComments"><?php wp_list_comments('type=all&avatar_size=60');?></ol>
    </div><!-- end #commentspost -->

<?php if ('closed' == $post->comment_status) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>

 <?php } 
 else { // this is displayed if there are no comments so far ?>

    <?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) { ?>
        <!-- If comments are open, but there are no comments. -->
<div id="commentspost">
    <h2 class="title">0 <?php _e('Comments', 'wpzoom'); ?></h2>
  <p><?php _e('You can be the first one to leave a comment', 'wpzoom'); ?>.</p>
</div>
     <?php } else { // comments are closed ?>
        <!-- If comments are closed. -->
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>

<?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>

<div id="respond">
<div class="cleaner">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="cancel-comment-reply"><p><?php cancel_comment_reply_link(); ?></p></div>

<?php if ( get_option('comment_registration') && !$user_ID ) : ?>
<p><?php _e('You must be', 'wpzoom'); ?> <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>"><?php _e('logged in', 'wpzoom'); ?></a> <?php _e('to post a comment.', 'wpzoom'); ?></p>
<?php else : ?>

<?php comment_form(); ?>

<?php if ( $user_ID ) : ?>

<p><?php _e('Logged in as', 'wpzoom'); ?> <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/profile.php"><?php echo $user_identity; ?></a>. <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="Log out of this account"><?php _e('Log out', 'wpzoom'); ?> &raquo;</a></p>

<?php endif; ?>
<div class="cleaner">&nbsp;</div>
<?php comment_id_fields(); ?>
<?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>
</form>
<?php endif; // If registration required and not logged in ?>
</div>
<?php endif; // if you delete this the sky will fall on your head ?>
```

Unless of course I am wrong about this and it should be included in loop.php ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's not *that* simple.

The function `wp_list_comments` lists all the comments of the post at once, so you can't directly insert your lines to modify each comment.

You have some options:

1. Pull the comments in some other way that allows you to obtain them individually
2. Store the comments code somehow and edit it to insert what you want
3. Check [this](http://www.studiograsshopper.ch/code-snippets/customising-wp_list_comments/) and [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments): the `wp_list_comments` function allows you to specify some callback functions to be applied to each comment. I'm sure you can use them to do what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

The function `wp_list_comments()` displays all the comments, in order to show de like/dislike button you need to create a custom callback function.
Take a look [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments).